# How does the JavaScript .apply method work?

Tags: javascript, callback, call, apply

I'm not asking how to use it. I know how to use it.

But when apply invokes the function that called it, how exactly does it pass an array of arguments into a function that was not written to take an array for an argument? Does it combine its given arguments array with the called functions "arguments"?

I looked at the latest ECMAscript specifications for .apply and .call, but I didn't really see anything about underlying logic.

Any explanation would be welcome. I'm new to JavaScript, and want to better understand what's going on under the hood. I'm currently trying to recreate some of the basic functions on my own, and this one is giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: It is under the hood. It is implemented outside JavaScript; and JavaScript interpreter can do whatever it wants. You cannot implement `apply` without `apply` (barring `eval` siliness), as it is the only thing in JavaScript that provides this functionality. You might as well ask "how does `console.log` access the console", or "how does `setTimeout` schedule a timeout"; it's just what it does.

Comment: I think it depends on each engine.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan, that was exactly what I wanted to know. I'd argue it's different than something like console.log though. That is API based. The window of many environments has a console namespace. Apply doesn't have appear to have anything to do with outside environments. Though maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: Whether it is "outside environment" or not, it is API: `Function` API, to be exact. The same way `console.log` does something to a console (i.e. write to it), `Array.prototype.push.apply` does something to `Array.prototype.push` (i.e. invoke it).

Comment: @Amadan, never thought of it like that. Huh. I did some googling after your comment. I didn't realize how much JavaScript was engine dependent. I didn't even realize there *were* such different engines. I now understand why people sometimes talk about ECMAScript requiring one thing, and "JavaScript" doing something different. Puts JS in a whole new light for me. So to know "how" apply works, I'd have to look at what a specific engine decided to do for it, and that wouldn't even be in JS, that would be in C/C++ or whatever?

Comment: Yes, `apply` is implemented in whatever JavaScript engine is implemented. They all do the same thing (ECMAScript being very strict about what `Function.prototype.apply` should do), but "how" is entirely an internal implementation detail for an engine.

Comment: @rPat: You can try looking at the ECMAScript spec on apply. ES specification is not written for programmers, it is written for javascript implementers. If you follow exactly the algorithm in the ES spec and write a C/Java/Python/Swift program with it you'd get the apply method. Note that historically the ES spec was/has been/is written by having the various browser vendors sit down and discuss how they implement something and writing down that implementation detail to try to cover as many browser's implementation as possible. In other words, the specification is reverse engineered.

Comment: @rPat: Also, you shouldn't be surprised that languages sometimes have things not implemented in the language itself. One example is the `sizeof` thing in C which looks like a function but is actually an operator that has no implementation in any library - it is processed directly by the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3).

We have to take the argArray and create what will be the arguments object pseudo array.

Essentially

```
Function.prototype.apply = function apply (thisArg, argArray) {
    var len = argArray.length;
    var n = ToUint32(len);
    var argList = []; // where this is a List not an array.
    var index = 0;
    var indexName;
    var nextArg;
    while (index < len) {
        indexName = ToString(index);
        nextArg = argArray[indexName];
        argList.push(nextArg);
        index++;
    }
    return this['[[Call]]'](func, thisArg, argList); // ignore the syntax however
                                                     // This is the line where the function
                                                     // will be called and provide 
                                                     // the thisArg and thisArray
}
```

I omitted some of the type checking that happens but this is essentially pretty close to what the spec dictates as how `Function.prototype.apply` is implemented. We craft our own object and build up the `argList` prior to calling the function.

Its important to note. that the internal method named `[[Call]]` is different than `Function.prototype.call`.

Comment: And following the spec, List is an implementation specific type, right? It's not part of the JS I can use, it's a type under the hood used to store arguments? I think this is the answer. The specs do indeed say how apply is run. You wrote them out really clearly too, thank you.

Comment: Yes all the stuff wrapped in double square braces `[[]]` are implementation specific. And in this case the `List` is as well. See the spec about it https://es5.github.io/#x8.8

Answer (score 2):

> how exactly does it pass an array of arguments into a function that was not written to take an array for an argument

You are misunderstanding how this works. `apply` does *not* pass an array of arguments to the object. It *takes* an array and then uses that to dynamically build a function call, similarly to what you could do with an `eval` statement (but it does it natively).

For example, an `eval` statement could work like this:

```
function buildFromArray(funcName, arrayOfArgs)
{
    var functionCall = funcName + "(";

    for ( var i = 0; i < arrayOfArgs.length; i++ )
    {
        //Very simplified, only allows for string args
        functionCall += "\"" + arrayOfArgs + "\"";

        if ( i < arrayOfArgs.length - 1 ) functionCall += ",";
    }

    functionCall += ")";

    //Now we run the compiled call which will be something like:
    //myFunction("one","two")
    eval( functionCall );
}

buildFromArray( "myFunction", [ "one", "two" ] );
```

This is very simplified, but you can see how an array is never passed to the function `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

`Function.prototype.apply` is implementation-specific: it is implemented in the JavaScript engine itself. There is really no way to replicate it, as when you call it it uses the C* API to tell the engine to call the function you want to call. User code can't manipulate the internal API, so there's no way to implement `Function.prototype.apply` without native code.

[image: "Source code" of <code>Function.prototype.apply</code>]
*"Source code" of `Function.prototype.apply` according to `Function.prototype.toString` in V8*

* Assuming a JS engine written in C. Replace with whatever language <insert JS engine here> is written in.